# Pug (Jade) base HTML Page: Cannot find element: #app

Tags: vue.js, vibed

I use vibed server. It use Pug preprocessor (before known as Jade). Here is my page code:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        script(src="https://unpkg.com/vue")
        script(src="app.js")
        title Hello, World
    body
        h1 Hello World
        #app
            |{{message}}
```

It generate next HTML output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script><script src="app.js"></script><title>Hello, World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <div id="app">
            {{message}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My app.js code:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    });

    app.$mount('#app');

}
```

But it's do not work. In browser console I am getting next error:
`Cannot find element: #app`

upd: moving `script(src="app.js")` to down helped. But is there any better variant? Or it's ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really two ways to handle it. One is to move the script to the bottom of the page, and the second is to use an event to trigger your code when the page is loaded.

The way you typically listen for the page to be loaded these days (without jQuery) is to listen for the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var app = new Vue(...)
});
```

The primary difference between the `DOMContentLoaded` and the `load` event being that `DOMContentLoaded` fires when all the DOM content has been parsed, and the `load` event waits for *everything* to be loaded including images, and stylesheets, and other things.